# HTML class not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

See my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/xvq6ofhh/

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var listEditPane = $('#editpane');

  console.log($(listEditPane).find('.input-highlight').length); // 2
  $(listEditPane).find('.input-highlight').removeClass('.input-highlight');
  console.log($(listEditPane).find('.input-highlight').length); // still 2 ???
});
```

The class is not removed, the length is still staying the same. What am I missing?

```
$(listEditPane).find('.input-highlight').removeClass('.input-highlight');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.removeClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) expects the name(s) of the class(es) to remove, but you are passing a selector `'.input-highlight'`. Remove the `.` from the beginning:

```
$(listEditPane).find('.input-highlight').removeClass('input-highlight');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xvq6ofhh/1/